# converting a dgCMatrix to data frame

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I would like to convert a sparse matrix into a data frame of the type (row,column, value).  I have found questions such as http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Converting-sparse-matrix-to-data-frame-in-Matrix-package-td2332012.html that in the question start with row,column,value and create a sparse matrix.  I want the inverse, and I cannot use the as.matrix function, because the matrix is too large.  Here is a small example.

```
r = c(1,2,2,3,3)
c = c(4,1,2,3,5)
v = c(1,2,1,3,1)

a = sparseMatrix(i=r,j=c,x=v) 

3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . . . 1 .
[2,] 2 1 . . .
[3,] . . 3 . 1
```

Can I get a data.frame

```
  r c v
1 1 4 1
2 2 1 2
3 2 2 1
4 3 3 3
5 3 5 1
```

Thank you

Comment: not a matrix inverse, the question I pointed to started with vectors to create a data frame, then created a dense matrix.  I wanted to start with a sparse matrix, and get a data frame of (row,col,value).  I want to invert his problem, not invert the matrix.

Comment: oh, I see. Still, it's an open question (for me) of how to use generic ``matrix`` methods (such as ``MASS::ginv``, for example), with ``sparseMatrix`` objects without resolving to ``as.matrix``. I thought you were after a similar thing, but sadly the accepted answer does not solve it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
b = as.data.frame(summary(a))
#   i j x
# 1 2 1 2
# 2 2 2 1
# 3 3 3 3
# 4 1 4 1
# 5 3 5 1
```

If you need the same order as in your example, you can use

```
b = b[order(b$i),]
#   i j x
# 4 1 4 1
# 1 2 1 2
# 2 2 2 1
# 3 3 3 3
# 5 3 5 1
```

Another alternative, though not quite as neat, is to use

```
b = as(a, "dgTMatrix")
cbind.data.frame(r = b@i + 1, c = b@j + 1, x = b@x)
```

Comment: Any idea whether this approach is indeed cheaper than ``as.matrix %>% as.data.frame``  approach? (colnames doesn't matter)

Comment: also, in the first case ``b %*% t(b)`` returns the following error:``requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments``. I don't see how can we avoid ``as.matrix`` here

Comment: @Nutle your comments are't really applicable here. As noted already by OP you seem to have mistaken that the question is about inverse matrices - it is not.  Maybe consider deleting your comments in case they could inadvertently be misleading to other readers?

Comment: I will cite the exact words from the OP's question: ``and I cannot use the as.matrix function, because the matrix is too large. ``

Comment: Finally, while some users may be misled, the others may be googling for ``cannot use as.matrix function`` and ``matrix too large`` and find the discussion. But if you think otherwise, say and I will delete my comments.

Comment: Yes, I do think that this answers the question that was asked by OP.  If you have a different question about a different topic you should ask it as a new question.  That's not what comments are for.